# How to clear react-select values on button click without adding it to options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select` and I want to clear the selected value on button click without adding it to the `options` property

I have tried

1. Using state to manipulate the options property , but Apparently on calling `clearValue()` method, automatically pushes to the options array by default.

**Problem**

How do I tell `react-select` to just clear the selected values and not add it in the options array anywhere ?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const selectInputRef = useRef();

  const onClear = () => {
    selectInputRef.current.select.clearValue();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Gender</h1>
      <Select
        isMulti
        ref={selectInputRef}
        options={[
          { value: "male", label: "Male" },
          { value: "female", label: "Female" }
        ]}
      />
      <button onClick={onClear}>Clear Value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-clear-input-forked-p48kh?file=/src/App.js:0-607)

Comment: In other words: You want to remove the currently selected value from the options alltogether?

Comment: @trixn yes that is what i want .. ideally it should be a function call .. so for ex I can remove those options on save

Comment: In that case you need to manage the options in component state and remove it, when the button is clicked.

Comment: @trixn I don't want `react-select` to change it's default behaviour of re adding elements.. i Just want to do it on a particular time i.e onButtonClick

Comment: @trixn I have already tried it in prod version of the code.. it doesnt work .. react-select automatically re adds them .. i would appreciate it if you would help me :(

Comment: It isn't "re-adding" it. It has never been removed in the first place. This is the default behaviour of a select and I can't think of any use case where you want to remove an option entirely when you de-select it. If you want to control which items are in the options array, why can't you just make it a state and remove it there?

Comment: @trixn what about the use-case of removing an element from options array on save for that particular element? and if i just make a state and remove it there it is still selected in the input field of select which looks odd to the end users of the site

Comment: @trixn adding more to that if i cross those existing selected values in `select` input field then it adds it back to the options array regardless of if i am using state or not.. pls if you have a soultion can you try out my codesandbox pls

Comment: It hasn't removed them from the options array. It just doesn't display them, in the dropdown, if they are already selected. The options are still in the options array as you provided a static array that never changes. `react-select` will not add or remove any options from it. I'll provide an example of how to manage the options yourself.

Comment: @trixn gotcha.. thanks will be waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manage the state of the selected values and the options yourself and manipulate it accordingly:

```
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { value: "male", label: "Male" },
    { value: "female", label: "Female" }
  ]);

  const handleClear = () => {
    setOptions((currentOptions) => currentOptions.filter((currentOption) => !selected.includes(currentOption)));
    setSelected([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Select Gender</h1>
      <Select isMulti value={selected} options={options} onChange={setSelected} />
      <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear Value</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-select-clear-input (forked)]

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add isClearable prop as:

```
<Select
  isMulti
  value={selected}
  options={options}
  onChange={setSelected}
  isClearable
/>
```